# Microsoft Graph Calendar CTAG/Changekey Not Changing

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to synchronise `365 Calendar` appointments with our internal CRM software calendar using the **Graph API** however the `CTAG` or `changekey` on the calendars do not change to signify an update has been made regardless of how many events I create/change/delete on 365.

Ideally I would just do a list calendars API call which returns the list of calendars and CTAG/changekeys so i know which calendars have been updated. I really don't want to have to get all of the events and compare the individual ETAG/changekeys every sync occurrence.

Tried via custom script and using **Microsoft Graph Explorer**, identical JSON response every time regardless of how many changes i make in my calendar.

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/4d591251-dd02-4bb8-9e80-9c66c526c7fe/calendars/`

```
 {
     "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('4d591251-dd02-4bb8-9e80-9c66c526c7fe')/calendars",
     "value": [
         {
             "id": "AAMkADFmODMyZWEwLWFmNjQtNDUyMS04YTk4LTFmZGViNzkyZWQyZQBGAAAAAABre3wS1gY0TIgCJhhYQAL5BwDZKoqjQvz8SoX7OCU5oF96AAAAYg1SAABRW8zpitFfR41s0yU_eudNAAlt2l4DAAA=",
             "name": "Calendar",
             "color": "auto",
             "changeKey": "ZqOtKvQcnUym2xGHcFiCNQAC7AE=",
             "canShare": true,
             "canViewPrivateItems": true,
             "canEdit": true,
             "owner": {
                 "name": "Liam Hill",
                 "address": "liam@contoso.com"
             }
         }
     ] 
 }
```

Comment: The Calendar's `changeKey` only tells you if the Calendar resource itself has changed (i.e. they renamed the calendar), not the events it contains.

Comment: Thats a bit strange since the CalDAV documentation states that:


"The calendar ctag is like a resource etag; it changes when anything **in** the calendar has changed. This allows the client application to quickly determine that it does not need to synchronize any changed events.
"

If the ctag doesn't change that means you would need to check every individual relevant event in every calendar to find out if changes had been made. When you're talking 1000 calendars, that's a serious hit to the system.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Is there possibly a better way to identify calendars that have events who have been updated? ie if i have 1000 calendars, what is the best way to identify which ones need to be synchronised without hammering the API retrieving lists of events constantly?

Comment: Have you looked at [Delta queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-events?tabs=http)?

Answer (score 1):

The changeKey that you are expecting to change will be reflected by this end point:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/4d591251-dd02-4bb8-9e80-9c66c526c7fe/events/AAMkADljY2EwNjU2LWVhYTItNDlmMy05ZWE1LTA5Zjc5YzhhZTMyYwBGAAAAAAAJYBHio4VlTKwYgFRcz_44BwC0bqbZ5NLFRoWa_zAJHejIAAAAAAENAABqBW9fyky-T4ye-miQ6gd0AAK83UeaAAA=

Also if you want to track a calendar for any changes that happen in specific period of time then you should work with Delta Query and resource you would use in this case will be CalendarView which also needs a date range.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview

Let me know if you need a working sample or if you requirement is some thing else.